# How to store multiple images for a single row/object in Django so that I can retrieve them or perform other query operations easily?

Tags: python, django, database

I am trying to build an api for a mobile application about house rents. The user may post multiple images of his house while posting an ad. How do I save them? I thought of Creating one-to-many relationship with My Ad class and an Image class, is there anything better? I've given a part of what I am talking about.

```
class RentPost(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = True)
    description = models.Textarea()

class Images(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(RentPost, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I thing you are following a good approach. Don't forget to add an `ImageField()` to your `Images` class and upload them to your `media` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion